# How to fetch an array of arrays in Perl?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I’m trying to fetch some array arrays in Perl but I get a database error, however in the debug I can see the right values.

```
my $worker_names = $self->glpi->db->query(
        'select user_name from report_users'
    );
 
    my @all = @{$worker_names->arrays->flatten->to_array};
 
    if ($worker_name ne '') {
        @all = ( $worker_name );
    }
 
    # name => [ public, privat, phabricator ]
    my $table;
    for my $user_name (@all) {
        $table->{$user_name}->[0] = '00 Stunden 00 Minuten';
        $table->{$user_name}->[1] = '00 Stunden 00 Minuten';
        $table->{$user_name}->[2] = '00 Stunden 00 Minuten';
    }
 
    $glpi_hours->hashes->each( sub {
        my $row = $_[0];
 
        $table->{$row->{'name'}}->[0] = $row->{'public_actiontime'};
        $table->{$row->{'name'}}->[1] = $row->{'private_actiontime'};
    });
 
    $phabricator_hours->hashes->each( sub {
        my $row = $_[0];
 
        $table->{$row->{'name'}}->[2] = $row->{'phab_time'};
    });
```

I get the error:

```
DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_hashref failed: fetch() without execute() at /var/www/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.3/lib/site_perl/5.28.3/Mojo/mysql/Results.pm line 55.       
  # Fetch sql data
52
  my $hash = $to->{type} eq 'hash';
53   
  my $sql_data
54
    = $to->{list} && $hash ? $self->sth->fetchall_arrayref({})
55  
    : $to->{list}          ? $self->sth->fetchall_arrayref
56   
    : $hash                ? [$self->sth->fetchrow_hashref]
57
    :                        [$self->sth->fetchrow_arrayref];
58
59
  # Optionally expand
60
  if ($mode) {
```

The problem is the array `my @all = @{$worker_names->arrays->flatten->to_array};` which isn’t working like it should.
I use also mojolicious as a framework.

When i run that in my browser, i can see the values of the fetch, first the error and after that i see the values been in the stash.

Comment: This looks like you are using a proprietary system to talk to the database that is built upon DBI. Your error message doesn't directly relate to the code. We would at least need line numbers to help you, but probably that error comes from code you haven't shown us. It looks like there is an abstraction layer, maybe Mojo::mysql, but I'm not familiar with it. The error means you are trying to ask a statement handle for data before it's actually executed a query. Your typical DBI interaction is `prepare`, `execute` and `fetch`. I don't know what `query()` does.

Comment: @Dex Don't paste code into comments. Add it to your question with the edit button if it is relevant.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your post. What is in `$self->glpi->db`? What is `$glpi_hours`? Where is that debugging statement that shows _the right values_

Comment: $self->glpi->db is the database connection, there is the query function which executes the sql statement, I get the right data. $glpi_hours is the an sql statement as $worker_names

Comment: I noticed that I get the error when this line is active:  ``` my @all = @{$worker_names->arrays->flatten->to_array};```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the result was empty because i gave the values to the array, through the collection, the result stays empty.